# Vue 3 pass tamplate part to another component

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue 3 application with router. (Using Bootstrap)

I have deep component in header, and main container (page in RouterView).

**Question:** I want to show few icons in header, but use it from page component.
What I must to use to do that?

I try to send template, dynamic import and etc, but as i understand it`s wrong ways.

I have same struct:

```
App  
  Header  
      Title  
      Icons  
  LeftMenu  
  MainContant  
      PageTitle   
      PageContant <- RouterView
  Footer
```

So I have special template to Header Icons for each page. And I want to work with icons from page component. For example make submit icon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if I understand the question correctly. But from what I get you want to have a slot in your Header component - [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#slots).
So you can use it in MainContainer as follows:

```
<div>
  <Header>
    <Icon />
  </Header>
</div>
```

In this case you'll have access to the Icon components in your MainContainer template.

Comment: I have same struct (I edit my question, because it is impossible mark in comment)
So I have special template to Header Icons for each page. And I want to work with icons from page component. For example make submit icon.